# MassTransit Integration with StructureMap 3.0.3

Tags: structuremap, masstransit

I am attempting to use MassTransit in my application that is StructureMap based.  I have followed the code examples provided by the MassTransit site, but seem to be having some issues getting it to work.

Here is my StructureMap Registry class:

```
using MassTransit;
using StructureMap;
using StructureMap.Configuration.DSL;
using StructureMap.Graph;
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class MassTransitRegistry : Registry
    {
        public MassTransitRegistry()
        {
            Scan(scan =>
            {
                scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("MyCompany"));
                scan.AddAllTypesOf<IConsumer>();
            });

            try
            {
                // Register the ServiceBus.
                var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
                {
                    sbc.UseRabbitMq();
                    sbc.ReceiveFrom(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MassTransitQueue"]);
                    sbc.UseControlBus();
                    sbc.UseJsonSerializer();
                    sbc.SetConcurrentConsumerLimit(12);

                    sbc.Subscribe(s => s.LoadFrom(ObjectFactory.Container));
                });

                ObjectFactory.Container.Inject<IServiceBus>(bus);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be with the MassTransit.StructureMap integration NuGet package.  It seems that this package requires StructureMap 2.6.4.0.  I cannot really change out my StructureMap version since I have code written that now works with the new way StructureMap is written in 3.0.

Does anyone know of a work around to this issue?

Regards,
Richard Onorato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this. MassTransit requires a signed version of StructureMap and Jeremy had made it clear he's not going to be generating a signed version.

Also, MT still supports .NET 3.5 and StructureMap 3.0 does not. You'll have to downgrade to StructureMap 2.6 or just ignore the integration package for MT and register your handlers manually.

There's an existing issue around this topic https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/pull/238.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I did go ahead an pull in just the MassTransit structuremap integration project into my solution and made the necessary changes to it to get it to work.  So I am now good, but it now means I have one more project to manage.